# How to query Microsoft Access Database fields from VBA in Excel

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, excel

I am currently writing a program to save stuff entered in a form in Excel into a database in Access. I am trying to increment a primary key field within Access by "1" whenever I add data from the fields in my Excel form.

Because I have declared this field as a PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL field, it doesn't allow me add another row of data unless the primary key field has been declared. I do not want the user to enter the PK data, as that would be silly.

How would I go about doing DDL from Excel into Access like say `MAX(CustomerID)` to find the maximum ID wihtin the Access table then adding `MAX(CustomerID) + 1` into the ID field using `RS.FIELD("CustomerID") = MAX(CustomerID) + 1`.

I would be grateful for any help in this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe its my misunderstanding, but why cant you use autonumber in MSAccess?

Comment: The Autonumber will be appropriate only if the ID is being used only for internal record-keeping purposes (e.g., to related records in a child table to those in a parent table). If the ID is being exposed to the users, you need to use your own code for incrementing an ID field. VBA code for doing that in Access has been posted all over the place in any number of Access forums, so it oughtn't be hard to find (it's even been posted on SO!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea of using an AutoNumber field as suggested in other answers.

However if you wish to steer clear of AutoNumber you can use Access's DLookup function from your VBA in Excel:

```
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("CustomerID") = Access.DLookup("Max(CustomerID)", "Customer") + 1

...

rs.Update
```

Assuming your base table is `Customer`.

You would have to add the reference to Microsoft Access in Tools->References

Comment: This could be quite unsafe if there are several users.

Comment: Cheers i was looking for a way to do it in VB

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a column as Autoincrement in Access. Then it will get subsequent values automatically.

Comment: Thats a good idea. But sadly it has to be done in the VB side in excel. I'll up you for the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to create the form in access itself and then you can just use the auto number field of the database? Unless there is a specific reason to keep it in excel it seems like a bit of a convoluted solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the above DLookup function, you can also create a VBA function to retrieve the value for you, then embed this in your insert into.

```
Private Function GetNextPKID(MyConnectionString) as Integer
dim rs as adodb.recordset, cn as adodb.connection, sSQL as string

sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable"

set cn = new adodb.connection
set rs = new adodb.recordset
cn.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString
cn.Open
set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open(sSQL)

GetNextPKID = rs.Fields(0).Value + 1

cn.Close
set cn = nothing
set rs = nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Woah, didn't notice quite how old this question was. Hopefully this will be of some use to somebody.